# Cannot set toolset to the new v140_clang_3_7 in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2015, clang

So I just downloaded the new [Visual Studio Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) and am trying to get CMake to generate the correct platform toolset.

New in Update 1 there is a new toolset: Clang 3.7 with Microsoft CodeGen
[image]

Pretty exciting, huh!

Anyway, I am trying to get CMake to generate the correct toolset here.

**ASSUMPTION 1:** The name of the toolset that CMake would accept is `v140_clang_3_7`. I assume this because that is what is in parenthesis, and that is what is used in other toolsets, like `v120` etc.

So I setup a simple test case:

```
C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>ls
CMakeLists.txt  main.cpp

C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)


add_executable(TestEXE main.cpp)
C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>cat main.cpp


// use some fancy c++14 feature that VS doesn't have

template<typename T>
constexpr T doThing{};

int main(){}
C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>
```

Next, I run CMake with the correct arguments:

**ASSUMPTION 2:** I have the correct arguments

```
C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -T "v140_clang_3_7"
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in :
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



CMake Error in :
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/russe/Documents/TestCMAKECLANG/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/russe/Documents/TestCMAKECLANG/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>
```

Say WHAT! No `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` or `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` found.

So that doesn't work. Lets see, it could be just that `-T` isn't working properly. Lets test with `v120`

```
C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -T "v120"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31010.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31010.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/russe/Documents/TestCMAKECLANG

C:\Users\russe\Documents\TestCMAKECLANG>
```

[image]

Works like a newborn baby. Hmm.

Alright guys, whats next?

Comment: Are you sure CMake already supports the new toolchain? Have you the latest CMake version? Did you try with one from Git?

Comment: @usr1234567  I must be so naïve, thinking that CMake is a magical black box, just generating magic. I'll have to try the newer CMake, but maybe in a few weeks; it just came out yesterday.

Comment: Why not now? Usually CMake version are kind of save to update. And if you have a problem, you can simply install the older version again. Actually your old version might be capable of using the new toolchain. I have neither checked the Git commits or the code source itself.

Comment: It would seem that CMake will have to generate slightly a different MSBuild, aka vcxproj, file for PlatformToolset v140_Clang_3_7. For instance for a normal C1 compile it adds <ObjectFileName>$(IntDir)</ObjectFileName>. Presumably C1 realizes this is a directory and adds the object filename, clang does not so you really need <ObjectFileName>$(IntDir)%(filename).obj</ObjectFileName>. Even better would be for CMake to not add an <ObjectFileName> element as MSBuild does the right thing anyway.

Comment: To add to my previous comment. CMake has a bad habit of setting stuff explicitly when MSBuild would do the right, and maybe better, thing by default. Also note this won't solve your problem, I suspect Cmake has a hard coded list of toolsets and this needs to be extended. Just that even when it is other things need to be fixed as well

Comment: Don't you have to have `clang` and `clang++` in PATH?

Comment: Seems like it should be done somewhere around here : https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmGlobalVisualStudio14Generator.cxx

Comment: I dug around in there for a  while, with no success. Idk what's next

Answer (score -1):

I've looked into this and it doesn't look too bad.  I've pushed a first [prototype](https://github.com/Microsoft/CMake/tree/feature/clang_3_7) that's able to compile a real simple program.

I'll keep working on fixing things, but hopefully it can be a start to figure out the rest of the work needed.

There are two ways to invoke Clang.

The first one is to specify the toolset from the command-line

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -T v140_clang_3_7 ...
```

The second one is to set a target property on a project to have that one specifically use the Clang toolchain

```
set_property(TARGET ${project} PROPERTY VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_OVERRIDE "v140_clang_3_7")
```

Comment: Awesome. Any idea when this will be pushed upstream?